# How to pass column name as variable in dynamic query in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the below query, which gives the count of distinct values for each column. But I need to add a where clause condition in the query such as column1 = 'abc'. I am using this generic query so that I can use the same query with other tables also by passing the table name.

```
DECLARE @query VARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT @query = 
    'SELECT ' + SUBSTRING((SELECT ',' +'COUNT(DISTINCT(' + column_name + ')) AS ' + column_name + ' '  
     FROM information_schema.columns
     WHERE table_name = 'table_name'
     FOR XML PAT('')), 2, 100000) + 'FROM table_name'

--PRINT(@query)
EXECUTE(@query)
```

I tried passing it as below.

```
WHERE 
    table_name = 'table_name' 
    AND column1 = 'abc'     -- compilation error, obviously

WHERE 
    table_name = 'table_name' 
    AND 'column1' = 'abc'   -- not working, because it will compare the string values column1 and abc. and both are not equal
```

Then I just gave a try with the below query, but this is also not working, it's generating the wrong query when I try to print.

```
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX), @tname NVARCHAR(100), 
        @cname NVARCHAR(100), @acc_num NVARCHAR(50), @dp_code NVARCHAR(100)

SET  @cname = 'column_name';
SET @acc_num = 'xyz';
SET @tname = 'table_name';

DECLARE @query VARCHAR(MAX);

SET @SQL = ''
        ;with cols as (
        select Table_Schema, Table_Name, Column_Name, Row_Number() over(partition by Table_Schema, Table_Name
        order by ORDINAL_POSITION) as RowNum
        from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
        )


SELECT @query = 
    'SELECT ' + SUBSTRING((SELECT ',' +'COUNT(DISTINCT(' + QUOTENAME(column_name, '') + ')) As ' + QUOTENAME(column_name, '')+ ' '
    + ' WHERE ' + 'column_name' + ' = ''' + @acc_num + ''''  
             FROM cols
             WHERE 
             table_name = @tname
             for xml path('')),2,200000)  +  'FROM' @tname
        --for xml path(''); 

PRINT @query
--execute (@query)
```

Comment: `'FROM' @tname` will create a syntax error here. YOu should really be parametrising your statements too. ` ' WHERE ' + 'column_name' + ' = ''' + @acc_num + ''''  ` is wide open to injection. Use a parametrised statement with `sp_executesql`.

Comment: Also, the common method to get rid of the first character of a string is `STUFF({String,1,1,'')`. It's more reliable than `substring`.

Comment: This query will be used by internal team only. And not the part of application. I need to write this only to see the results

Comment: Internal or not, that does not give you a reason for bad coding practices. :)

Comment: When you have to start using dynamic sql to pass in column and table names something went wrong in the design.

Comment: @Larnu true, agreed. But is there any way to pass the column name ?

Comment: Yes, it'll take me a while to write up a solution, but possible.

Comment: Till the time you write the solution, can you guide me so that I can also start implementing in the right direction

Comment: See my comments above then :)

Comment: @Larnu didn't get it :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be what you are after. There's a few comments in the SQL you need to pay attention to:

```
DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(max),
        @tname sysname, --note the datatype change
        @cname sysname, --note the datatype change
        @acc_num nvarchar(50),
        @dp_code nvarchar(100); --This is never used in your sample query
SET  @cname = 'column_name';
SET @acc_num = 'xyz';
SET @tname = 'table_name';


SET @SQL = N'SELECT ' + NCHAR(13) + NCHAR(10) +
             STUFF((SELECT N',' + NCHAR(13) + NCHAR(10) +
                           N'       ' + N'COUNT DISTINCT(' + QUOTENAME(C.Column_Name) + N') AS ' + QUOTENAME(C.Column_Name)
                    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS C
                    WHERE C.Table_Name = @tname
                    ORDER BY C.ORDINAL_POSITION
                    FOR XML PATH(N'')),1,10,N'') + NCHAR(13) + NCHAR(10) +
             N'FROM ' + QUOTENAME(@tname) + NCHAR(13) + NCHAR(10) +
             N'WHERE ' + QUOTENAME(@cname) + N' = @Acc_Num;'

PRINT @SQL; --YOur debugging best friend
EXEC sp_executesql @SQL, N'@Acc_Num varchar(100)',@Acc_Num = @acc_num;
```

This parametrised the query instead, using `sp_executesql`, and nicely formats it for your `PRINT` statement.

If you don't understand then *please do ask*.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, what if I need to get the same result for all distinct `@Acc_Num`. So if there are 10 distinct values of `@cname` column in the table. it should return the 10 rows with distinct values count for each column. like it is returning for the given`@ Acc_Num`

Comment: Remove the `WHERE`, change the `SELECT` and add a `GROUP BY` in the dynamic statement. Just like you would a "normal" (non-dynamic statement) @viveknuna. *(And no need to pass the 2nd onwards parameters)*

Comment: could you please help in that

Comment: You need to be able to support the code @viveknuna, not me. As I said, if you don't understand, please ask (about what you don't understand). But please don't ask me to provide examples for every scenario, that's for you to do with the existing answer.

Comment: One small support. I need to the cname column with its value in  the returned results. I tried but couldn't do

Comment: Without seeing what you attempted, I don't know what the problem was, @viveknuna, but `PRINT @SQL` is there specifically to help you debug the dynamic statement.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191126/discussion-between-vivek-nuna-and-larnu).

Answer (score 0):

If you want a WHERE clause in the dynamic query, then you have to put it after the FROM clause in the dynamic query.

```
 ...
 for xml path('')),2,200000)  +  ' FROM '+ @tname
 + ' WHERE ' + 'column_name' + ' = ''' + @acc_num + ''''
```

Comment: No, the OP didn't ask how to solve for injection.  I only answered the question that was asked.

Comment: So because the OP didn't ask how to fix the injection you shouldn't? If you had a hole in your wall and you were asked to "fix" the hole, would you cover it will a piece of paper and pretend the problem is "solved" (you can't see it anymore), or fill it in properly? Not addressing a huge security flaw does not make this a good answer.

Comment: You're making an assumption that an injection risk exists.  The question doesn't state if or how the inputs are cleansed on the front end, or if there even are inputs.  This might be part of an unattended app that gets its variable values from the database.

Comment: That is a very poor assumption. There is no excuse to use `= ''' + @acc_num + ''''`,  when `@acc_num` can be a parameter. Attitudes like this are the reason injection is still so prevalent and why people aren't taught how to avoid it; because people that *should* know better don't follow good standards themselves. Educating people by providing a good answer is just as important as providing a correct one.